# Why was this question on writing a system tray app closed as Not-Constructive?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

The question is [How can I make a .NET Windows Forms application that only runs in the System Tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/995195/302677)

I was trying to figure out how to create a System Tray application and came across this question. It provided better information than what I had found online so far, so I was quite happy to see it. I had some trouble understanding the answers, however one of the [newer deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250051/302677) pointed to a good tutorial that helped me find my solution.

I wanted to upvote the deleted answer, but it was deleted by a moderator because it was a link-only answer, so I edited the answer to make it a complete answer and flagged it for a moderator to undelete so I could vote it up.

But instead of undeleting the answer, the moderator closed the question.

I feel this question provides a lot of great information and links to good resources related to creating a system tray application in .Net, and I don't understand why it got closed as not-constructive.

Why was it closed? And if this was a mistake, can I get it reopened?

(And if it does get re-opened, can a moderator undelete the answer I edited so I can vote on it? Its no longer a link-only answer, and I feel it provides the best answer for someone looking to learn how to create a System Tray application, but I can't undelete it because a moderator deleted it.)

Comment: @casperOne seems to be on a roll today...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta And re-closed a 2nd time by the same moderator. Community moderation at its finest...

Comment: @Rachel Are you arguing on the grounds of the question, or because you placed an answer (that was deleted, not by me) on a question that you knew was crappy and could use work?  Your motives in this are suspect.  It would have come across more genuine if you asked why the result of your flag to undelete your answer didn't result in it being undeleted.

Comment: @casperOne I am arguing on the grounds of the question because I could not find anything useful on Google until I came across that question. It helped me understand the process and find a solution to what I wanted. The deleted answer is not mine. I simply wanted to upvote it. I knew link-only answers often get deleted, so I edited it to copy some of the main information from the link into the answer itself, and flagged it for undeletion so I could vote it up. I didn't expect such a useful question to get closed instead.

Comment: The question helped you understand the process, or the answers did? The fact that it got reasonable answers does not make the question any better.

Comment: @Rachel Lists of examples are not useful on Stack Overflow.  It's equivalent to shopping recommendations, which we don't allow.  Bringing a summary from a link is a good thing, but in the future, please think of it in the context of the larger question.

Comment: @Bart Both. The question was the exact same as what I wanted to do, and the answers provided me with the explaination of what I needed (Replace `Form` with `ApplicationContext`, and create a `NotifyIcon`)

Comment: A Google search for "Writing a Windows system tray application with .NET" yields the closed question as the first match, and [Creating Tray Applications in .NET: A Practical Guide](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/) as the second match, which is the tutorial linked by the accepted answer.

Comment: @deceze I'm on a roll every day, but I'm not sure what you mean =)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am more likely to click on SO for answers than a blog post, and the blog post you listed was beyond my understanding at the time. I needed something simple, like the SO answers provided.

Comment: The fact that the question is closed does not change that at all. The information is still there. And the question still is not good, so why reopen it?

Comment: @Rachel: Well, the question is unlikely to be deleted, the OP already has his answer, and by your own admission the information is already good, so no new answers need to be posted. If someone wants to make the question better so that it's not a broken window, they can flag to reopen.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Except for the fact I couldn't easily understand the information until I came across the tutorial link in the deleted answer. I have made an edit to the question to try and remove some of the "broad recommendations" you are seeing. Please consider reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was closed Not Constructive because it asked (emphasis mine)

> **What's the correct way** to write a Windows system tray application in C#?
>
> Not an application that can minimize to the tray, but one that only
>   exists in the tray, and can have an icon tool tip and "right click"
>   menu.

There is no one right answer to that since there are many correct ways to create a system tray application, and the solution you use depends on what you're actually trying to do with your application, so the end result is a list of everyone's favorite way of making a tray application.

The question and answers are still quite useful for users trying to figure how to create an application that only exists in the system tray, so I edited the question to remove the words that could possibly lead to a not-constructive list of answers, and re-focused it on what the OP actually seemed to be asking, which was how to create a system-tray only application.

> What do I need to do to make a WinForms application run in the System Tray?
>
> Not an application that can minimize to the tray, but one that exists
>   only in the tray, and that has an icon tool tip and "right click"
>   menu.

And a moderator reopened the question.

Thanks to everyone for helping me understand this, and for your reopen votes :)

Comment: Why shouldn't this be deleted?  I'm not really sure what this adds to your question, and it also begs the question of if you know why or have an answer, why ask in the first place?  Most of it is just a rehash of your question, along with a "thank you" at the end.

Comment: @casperOne I posted this so I could mark it as accepted, although I know I can't accept it for two days. I didn't know the answer when I posted the question, however some of the comments have helped me understand the problem with the question, and lead to a resolution. I'd like to share that resolution so others can understand as well.

Comment: Wasn't all this already adequately covered? Why did you feel compelled to rehash it here?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It was covered in comments, but comments are not answers so I combined the relevant comments into one answer to accept it. The current answers do not contain this information. One states the question is asking for a tutorial, which isn't a reasonable explanation since the answer needed is only a few lines of code, and the other is that as written, it is too broad and that if anything we should lock it. While I understand now what words were making it too broad, I disagree that it should be locked. The answer was to edit out the offending words and reopen, which is what happened.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You may delete it if you want, but I thought it offered some things that were not there in the other answers, such as the exact words that made it too broad and the actual resolution to the question.

Comment: It's still not a great question, but that's part of the reason we have moderators: to solve disputes on borderline questions.  If everything were black and white, you wouldn't need moderators.  In any case, most of what you've said here is adequately covered elsewhere; note that the question has an [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/995195/revisions), so everyone can already see exactly what happened.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It may not seem like a great question from here, but to someone actually facing the same situation as the OP, it is a great question. I am guessing that's where large percentage of the current 54 upvotes comes from - Users facing the same situation and looking for an answer.

Comment: Note that the question currently has three new close votes on it.  If it closes again, I won't reopen.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I had noticed that, although I'm really not sure why those close votes are there. I thought the question was pretty straight forward and had one-right-answer. It is not overly broad since the code needed to make an application exist in the system tray only is fairly short. The top answer does list a lot of things to consider, although a lot of those things are not really relevant to what the OP was asking (such as WPF support, or dynamic context menus)

Comment: Because of the rampant existence of help vampires (Google it) on Stack Overflow, the community generally expects people to "show their work... what have you tried so far, and why didn't it work for you?"  This OP didn't do that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I looked through Google a bit and wasn't having much luck finding a clear, simple explanation of how to accomplish what I wanted until I came across that SO question. There are many ways to interact with the system tray, and I simply wanted a system-tray-only application. Oh well, even if it gets closed again at least the answer I found the most helpful now exists, and will hopefully help others. Still, would be a shame to close such a useful question. I thought one of the reasons SO exists is so people don't have to wade through random blog posts or forums to find solutions.

Comment: Closing doesn't mean the death of a question, only its imminent demise.  The post could live on the site indefinitely in its closed state.

Answer (score 14):

It's asking for a complete tutorial.  That's not really a reasonable expectation.  Has the author of the question demonstrated that he's performed some basic research, or do we have to teach him the entire concept from scratch?  That's what books are for.

The accepted answer scratches the surface, but the real meat is in an external link.

Comment: Did you see the deleted question I edited? There is a very simple answer to the question. You don't need a complete book or tutorial to answer it. You only need a few lines of code, and the user can figure out what they're doing from there

Comment: Google already has plenty of help for this.

Comment: Google was providing me with links that I was having trouble understanding, or that did not suit what I wanted. That SO question provided provided me with what I needed: simple explanations to a situation exactly similar to mine.

Comment: Also, it is not asking for a complete tutorial. It is merely asking how to accomplish something. The correct answer is only a few lines of code: Replace `Form1` in the `Application.Run` line of `Program.cs` with a class that inherits from `ApplicationContext`, and create a `NotifyIcon` in that class. That's it. That's the information I needed, and that I suspect many other users need too.

Comment: I've already reopened your question, based on the removal of the "correct" part.  Sooo many people want to be "correct."  There's nothing wrong with that in principle, but programming is an exercise in tradeoffs.  There is no "correct" way.  There is only the way that best meets your customer requirements.

Comment: Thank you, both for re-opening the question and for undeleting the answer that I found more helpful than the rest.

Answer (score 8):

It's a very broad question, and as written, it's 'not constructive'.  What is the canonical right way? Who can say?  The fact that it's interesting doesn't stop it from working within the framework of the Q & A that is Stack Overflow.

At best, it should be locked as Historically relevant (if there are a number of external links to it), otherwise the material is better left for a blog post somewhere than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps "the right way" was a bad choice of words. I made an edit to remove those words, and hope you will reconsider the close. The simple and short information provided is what I needed to know (replace `Form` with `ApplicationContext`, and create a `NotifyIcon`). This sort of information should be welcomed by SO, not turned away.