# Interpretation of "off topic" question: installing a MongoDB driver

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

I'm curious why a Stack Overflow question on [installing a MongoDB driver for PowerPC Macs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963394/install-mongodb-driver-for-php-to-xampp-on-a-powerpc-mac/12027438) would be closed as "off-topic".  I've read through the FAQs; this question seems to relate to a specific programming problem the OP was having difficulty with.

Would it have been better posted on another Stack Exchange site, or is there some revision that would have made it acceptable?

Additionally, at the the time the question was closed the question had an active bounty and the OP accepted an answer.  Closing the question refunded the bounty rather than awarding.  Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: isn't is belongs to http://superuser.com ?

Comment: the bounty was refunded by the Moderator closing the question

Comment: @Lucifer: the question relates to a programming-specific task, though .. installing a PHP driver for the MongoDB database.

Comment: @Sathya: I'm fine with the bounty being refunded to the OP (much better than lost) .. just trying to understand how the process works.  This is the first question I've answered where I would have had a bounty; "missed it by that much" apparently :).

Comment: @Lucifer I don't expect a community of power users to know how to get a tricky PHP driver installed. If the question was 'how do I install PHP' then perhaps, but this was quite technical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was me, and I think I did make a mistake here. I originally read the question as basically a request for tutorials to get the driver installed, which is quite open ended. It's not untypical for questions of this nature to avoid closing due to open bounties, which is why I refunded the bounty prior to closing it. So yes, the OP did get the bounty back.

In the context of the answer that you provided, the way I understood the question after reading it again changed, so I have reopened it. It does fit the FAQ well enough to stay on SO (IMHO), the community can override me on that if they feel differently. The OP can add the bounty again and reward it.

Sorry about that, I misunderstood precisely what the OP was asking and thought the question would lead to a bunch of link only answers (which in all actuality could have happened).

Comment: Thanks for reviewing Tim.  It was a specific installation challenge, and the answer will help others trying to install the MongoDB driver on PowerPC Macs :).

Comment: @Stennie Yeah, definitely. The quality of your answer is what made me do a double take. Thanks for being awesome :)